# The entity type <myType> is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: entity-framework

Using EF6, .NET 4.0

I have my own custom models and am using Database First approach. I've modified the edmx to use the same namespace as my custom models. I'm getting the error in the subject of the thread when running the code. The class 'User' does exist in my model and in my edmx. I also have my custom DbContext like so:

```
public class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    public MyEntities()
        : base("Name=MyEntities")
    {
        User = Set<User>();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: a look at the edmx might not go amiss if that is what you have modified...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I changed the namespace of the edmx to match that of my custom model, (e.g. MyApp.Models). I also changed some of the properties in the model designer. But that shouldn't affect this.

Comment: I've also tried changing the connection string, as suggested elsewhere, to remove the EntityFramework metadata, but then I get this error: "The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project"

Comment: So I ended up just switching to Code First and now everything works. Not really an "answer" to my original question, but I'm able to do what I want to do now.